# How to deal with Gradle and multi project configuration?

Tags: java, gradle, build-script

I have several projects [A, B, C], A depends on B and C.

I want to move my projects to a multi project build configuration. Today my projects live on SVN, completely isolated.

I was wondering if the only way to use the multi project build feature is if I move the projects to the same repository, imagine something like:

```
MyPorject 
--A 
----build.gradle 
--B 
---build.gradle 
--C 
----build.gradle 
--build.gradle
```

Suggestions are welcome! 
Thanks!

Comment: The projects doesn't need to be in the same repository. Also, you could add the references between each other using [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/what-is-maven.html).

Comment: Sorry I'm using Gradle not Maven

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I got 3 options from one guys of the Gradle project:

- Always check out all three projects in the same relative locations, and make one of them the root
- Use Subversion externals
- Relocate all projects to a shared Subversion repository

Here http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/how_to_deal_with_multi_project_configuration